# Whats wrong with this ASP.NET rewrite?

Tags: asp.net, mono, apache2, xsp

Actually its the mono version of asp.net, XSP.

In my begin request function i check the url and rewrite when necessary. In one case i do

```
context.RewritePath("~/App_Data/public" + path);
```

When i try to request images or anything i get a 404 instead of the content. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this isnt supported in mono ATM. HttpContext.Rewrite is but rewriting to files is not.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler o see the actual request. If the path is being rewritten the images would probably have to referenced as an absolute path..

But alas I have no experince with xsp so ....

Use fiddler to see the actual request

Comment: It doesnt help. Its not a redirect. Its internal.

Answer (score 0):

Images by default don't get handled by ASP.NET (at least on IIS). Are you able to confirm that image extensions are being handled by ASP.NET and not being directly served up?

Also, modify the code slightly:

```
string newpath = "~/App_Data/public" + path;
context.RewritePath(newpath);
```

And check the value of `newpath` to make sure it's a well-formed path. If `path` is not prefixed with a path delimiter then that may also be the cause of your woes.

Comment: `string path = CleanPath(context.Request);` which just deletes everything after `?` and is the uri.path value. So it is always /whatever/andfolder/file.ext. This works in the visual studios webserver and cassini last time i checked.

Comment: I have never heard of CleanPath, nor can I find it in the .NET libraries.

Comment: How does the modified code differ from the code posted in the question?

Comment: It is only so the poster can step through the code and inspect the result of the concatenation before feeding it to RewritePath.

Comment: CleanPath is my own. It looks like other ppl are having issues with mono+rewriting with files. I dont think its supported ATM. To be clear this works in ms asp.net

Comment: @acidzombie24 - Well that's probably not too helpful to the OP without some source code or a link to this CleanPath of yours.

Comment: lol. maybe you didnt notice. The background color in my name is to note i am op.